# javascript preg_match of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a link from a page between

`url: '` and `',`

I have tried a few different solutions found via google but the closest I have got is this

```
function pregmatch() {
    var re = new RegExp("url: '(.*)',", "g"),// the regex
       txt = 'some text'; // the text on page to be replaced by url
    newtxt = txt.replace(txt,re); // replace text with found url
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(txt,newtxt);
}
pregmatch();
```

but this simply replaces the `some text` with the regex `/url: '(.*)',/g` and not the url which what is needed.

I also tried `newtxt = txt.replace(txt,re[0]);` but that came back as undefined, I am a JS novice so any help is appreciated

**UPDATE:**

Ok I think some miss-understand what I'm trying to do so will try again

In the pages source there is a section:

```
url: 'http://somedomain.com/b3a4f5d2b725a8d',
```

On the page itself there is some text `hello world` which is situated perfectly for where I want to add the url on page, so i want to grab the url from the source and replace the `hello world` with the url.

ie `var txt = 'some text'` is not the string from where the url is but infact just text on page that will be replaced with the found url.

Comment: If you're trying to get the link, why are you using replace instead of match? Surely you're just after `url.match(/url:'(.*?)',/)[1]`

Comment: I did say I am a JS novice, I guess actually I am a novice JS novice.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
string.replace(regex, replacement);
```

Thus:

```
txt.replace(re, somereplacement);
```

But since you want to get a url, you might be better off using `.match`:

```
url = txt.match(re)[1];
```

And your `re` would be better with:

```
var re = new RegExp("url: '(.*?)',", "g");
```

This prevents matching more than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing matches of your regex in string `txt` with your regular expression.

Correct usage is:

```
var newtxt = txt.replace(re, "something_to_replace_with");
```

to get all matches:

```
var matches = txt.match(re);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without explicitly defining a regex object:

```
var reg = /url: '(.*?)',/;
var txt = "url: 'some text',";
if (reg.test(txt))
   alert(txt.match(reg)[1]);
```

Also be aware that

```
var txt = 'some text';
```

Will not match a regular expression looking for single quotes, because the single quotes used above are only used to define the variable as a string -- they don't actually exist as matchable text IN the string itself.